# Как с помощью jquery удалить все атрибуты у всех перечисленных элементов?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Например, чтобы по задумке такой код `$('div, ul, ol, p').removeAttr('class, align, width');` удалял бы из всех перечисленных тегов все перечисленные атрибуты, если они есть. Такой код работает только по-одному, вот так `$('div').removeAttr('class');`, но это не подходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/

> ... as of version 1.7, it can be a space-separated list of attributes.
>
> ... с версии 1.7 это может несколько названий атрибутов, разделенных пробелами.

```
$('div, ul, ol, p').removeAttr('class align width');
```

```js
console.log("before:", $("div")[0].outerHTML);
console.log("before:", $("p")[0].outerHTML);

$('div, ul, ol, p').removeAttr('class align width');

console.log("after:", $("div")[0].outerHTML);
console.log("after:", $("p")[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="aaa" width="200px"></div>
<p title="test" class="bbb"></p>
```